# Google Drvie Sdk How to move C folder from A folder to B folder?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to move specific folder from A folder to B folder.
and i don't want to copy and delete.
can i get some your information?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the Parents collection of the file to remove folder A from it and add folder B:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/parents